# ¿Porque react me rechaza mi .map?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

Soy nuevo en react y manejos de api.
Decidi empezar a hacer una pokedex con una api (Pokeapi) pero resulta que no me reconoce mi .map.
Les dejo el codigo:

```
  const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10&offset=1"
  const [poke, setPoke] = useState()
  const pokeApi = async () => {
const response = await fetch(url)
console.log(response.statusText)
const responseJSON = await response.json()
setPoke(responseJSON)
    }

  useEffect(() => {
      pokeApi()
    }, [])
```

Acontinuación dejo mi return.

```
  return (
<div>
<h1>Pokedex</h1>
<ul>
{ !poke ? 'Cargando...' : 
poke.map( (poke,index)=>{
  return <li>{poke.name}</li>
})}
</ul>
</div>
```

);

Al fijarme en mi localhost aparece el siguiente error:

> TypeError: poke.map is not a function

Si necesitan mas información me avisan y edito la consulta!

Comment: Puedes hacer un `console.log(responseJSON )` para ver qué contenidos tiene? Justo antes del `setPoke`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es porque no hay ningun dato con el nombre `name`, el `name` que estas tratando de mapear esta dentro de un array `results`

tu problema se resuelve de esta manera

```
<ul>
  {!poke ? 'Cargando...' :
    poke?.results?.map((poke, index) => {
     return <li key={index}>{poke.name}</li>
  })}
</ul>
```

Comment: Ohhh entiendo, gracias bro!

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const URI = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=10&offset=1"
const Component = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    useEffect(function(){
        fetch(URI)
        .then(response => {
            if(response.ok){
                response.json().then(data => setData(data))
            } else {
                // Error (Manejar error)
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            // Error (Manejar error)
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Pokedex</h1>
            {
                data && data.results ?
                    <ul>
                        {data.results.map((poke, index)=> <li key={index}>{poke.name}</li>)}
                    </ul>
                    
                :
                    <div>
                        <span>Cargando...</span>
                    </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Component;
```

Me parece que de esta forma podrías ver un resultado diferente, no uses ¨async¨ si no es con un try-catch, porque la aplicacion se rompe facilmente, si solo es una peticion puedes utilizar una promesa.

Recuerda utilizar variables con nombres descriptivos y pegar todo el codigo para reproducirlo.

Comment: Ya uno comento y me lo soluciono. De igual manera se agradece las recomendaciones para fomentar las buenas practicas! :)